# UIButtons non-responsive after being moved in from off iPad screen

Tags: ios, uibutton

The description might be a bit confusing, I've added pictures to try to illustrate what I'm describing.  Please let me know what I can clarify to help.

I have an iPad application with a main view that is a xib.  The size of the xib is 1024 by 1384 and is meant to be viewed in landscape mode.  There is a row of buttons that are visible at the bottom of the iPad screen.  When one of the buttons is pressed I move the frame so that these buttons are now at the top of the visible portion of the screen.  There are additional elements that start out offscreen but then come onscreen after the move.

The problem I'm having is that the UIButton that starts offscreen is not calling the IBAction associated with it.

I have tried to setUserEnabled to YES for it but that doesn't seem to be making any difference either.  I've also tried setNeedsDisplay after the animation is complete.

Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you verified that your connections are wired correctly in interface builder, correct?  It's usually worthwhile to go back and double-check.

Comment: I have verified that the connections are wired correctly in interface builder, both previously and once again in response to your comment.

Comment: when displaying the offscreen button, just write [self.view bringSubVieToFront:yourOffScrenButtonName];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add the view to the screen, it changes the view's size to fit the visible portion on the screen. As such, your frame is smaller than the total content area of the view. Moving the frame won't do anything for you; it will move the existing visible content up, but it won't change the view to show new visible content.

Instead, you want to be changing the view's `bounds.origin`, which will change the visible portion of the view's content.

**Edit:**
Note that even though the view was shrunk, I suspect that the `clipsToBounds` property on your main view was set to `NO`. That means that it will actually continue displaying content outside of the bounds, which is why it shows up. However, hit-testing only works on the actual frames of the view. All that stuff that shows up outside the bounds is still visible, but it's not *interactible*.